# how to solve error:1365 division by 0 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to generate insert to table from query but this query might throw a division by zero error:

```
insert into rpp
select IFNULL(IF((IF(((((((`s`.`smi` + `s`.`jmb`) + `s`.`ruah`) +
`s`.`stg_jd`) + `s`.`jdw_pro`) / `p`.`rate`) <= 2),
((`p`.`rate` * 4) - ((((`s`.`smi` + `s`.`jmb`) + `s`.`ruah`) 
+ `s`.`stg_jd`) + `s`.`jdw_pro`)),0) > 0),
(FLOOR((IF(((((((`s`.`smi` + `s`.`jmb`) + `s`.`ruah`) 
+ `s`.`stg_jd`) + `s`.`jdw_pro`) / `p`.`rate`) <= 2),
((`p`.`rate` * 4) - ((((`s`.`smi` + `s`.`jmb`) + 
`s`.`ruah`) + `s`.`stg_jd`) + `s`.`jdw_pro`)),
0) / `p`.`bets`)) * `p`.`bets`),0),0) AS `rp`
FROM (`produk` `p`LEFT JOIN `stok` `s` ON ((`p`.`kode` = `s`.`kode_produk`)))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add logic which detects a zero in the denominator and in this case insert some other value.  By the way, your query is illegible.

Comment: God, this is the ugliest query I've ever seen. You really think someone will try understanding this ?

Comment: Iam Sory my query ugliest. simply : insert into select ifnull (1/0,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this.

Add logic, that you divide by 1 instead or however you want to handle it. For this there's this wonderful function `IF()` which works like `IF(condition, then, else)`, for example `IF(my_column = 0, 1, my_column)`.

Another way is by setting your sql_mode accordingly. Have a look at the sql_mode [error_for_division_by_zero](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero).

> The ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO mode affects handling of division by
>   zero, which includes MOD(N,0). For data-change operations (INSERT,
>   UPDATE), its effect also depends on whether strict SQL mode is
>   enabled.
>
> If this mode is not enabled, division by zero inserts NULL and produces no warning.
>
> If this mode is enabled, division by zero inserts NULL and produces a warning.
>
> If this mode and strict mode are enabled, division by zero produces an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE
>   and UPDATE IGNORE, division by zero inserts NULL and produces a
>   warning.
>
> For SELECT, division by zero returns NULL. Enabling
>   ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO causes a warning to be produced as well,
>   regardless of whether strict mode is enabled.
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.4, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO is deprecated. In MySQL
>   5.7.4 through 5.7.7, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO does nothing when named explicitly. Instead, its effect is included in the effects of
>   strict SQL mode. In MySQL 5.7.8 and later, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
>   does have an effect when named explicitly and is not part of strict
>   mode, as before MySQL 5.7.4. However, it should be used in conjunction
>   with strict mode and is enabled by default. A warning occurs if
>   ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO is enabled without also enabling strict
>   mode or vice versa. For additional discussion, see SQL Mode Changes in
>   MySQL 5.7.
>
> Because ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO is deprecated, it will be removed
>   in a future MySQL release as a separate mode name and its effect
>   included in the effects of strict SQL mode.

Comment: Ok Thank You, With the addition of ignore is resolved